# Extension of induction principle proof.

Tags: induction

i was wandering if is there an extension of the induction principle whether number the integer variables are more than 1?

Example... if i need to prove that $p(n)$ is true then i would start by prove $p(0)$ and assuming for each $k <= n$ is true i'd try to prove $p(n+1)$ is also true...

Is there some generalization whether the statement is of the form $p(n,m)$? and so on and so forth...

Comment: Induction relies heavily on the concept of 'successor'. What would be the successor of a given $(m,n)$ ?

Comment: So should it depend on the particular statement?

Comment: Fix $n$ and do induction for $m$; fix $m$ and do induction for $n$, perhaps.

Comment: @GitGud, it depends on the particular case ;-)

Answer (score 1):

As the comments indicate, it is often possible to do induction on each variable separately. Where that isn't useful, you have to define some "successor" relation between $(m, n)$ tuples that allow the induction to go through. One example is the following. Define:

$\begin{align}
   C(m, n)
      = \frac{(2 m)! (2 n)!}{n! m! (m + n)!}
\end{align}$

Prove that $C(m, n)$ is always an integer.

To do this, we first prove that $C(m, 0)$ is an integer for $m \ge 0$, then prove a relation between $C(m, n), C(m + 1, n), C(m, n + 1)$ that implies that if the first two are integers, so is the third. But:

$\begin{align}
C(m, 0)
  &= \frac{(2 m)! 0!}{0! m! m!} = \binom{2 m}{m}
\end{align}$

which certainly is an integer.

Now do an induction over $n$ to prove $C(m, n)$ is always an integer.

**Base:** If $n = 0$, we are done by the above.

**Induction:** We assume $C(m, n)$ is an integer for all $m \ge 0$, and consider:

$\begin{align}
C(m + 1, n) + C(m, n + 1)
  &= \frac{(2 m + 2)! (2 n)!}{(m + 1)! n! (m + n + 1)!}
         + \frac{(2 m)! (2 n + 2)!}{m! (n + 1)! (m + n + 1)!} \\
  &= \frac{(2 m)! (2 n)!}{m! n! (m + n + 1)!}
               \cdot \left(
                       \frac{(2 m + 1) (2 m + 2)}{m + 1}
                         + \frac{(2 n + 1) (2 n + 2)}{n + 1}
                     \right) \\
  &= \frac{(2 m)! (2 n)!}{m! n! (m + n + 1)!}
               \cdot 4 \cdot (m + n + 1) \\
          &= 4 C(m, n)
\end{align}$

As claimed, if $C(m, n)$ and $C(m + 1, n)$ are integers, so is $C(m, n + 1)$. Together with the base, this implies $C(m, n)$ is always an integer.

As a final remark, I haven't been able to find an example of a direct "successor" relation between pairs. This is the closest I've seen.